# How to pass a structure to a STL map?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, struct

```
typedef struct
{
    pthread_t threadId;
    int       acceptSocketD;
    char      *message;
} threadData;

map <unsigned int, threadData> serverPortNumberThreadId;
map <unsigned int, threadData> :: iterator serverPortNumberThreadIdIter;
```

usage:

```
threadData obj; 
obj.threadId      = 0;
obj.acceptSocketD = 0;
obj.message       = "Excuse Me, please!";

serverPortNumberThreadId.insert (3490, obj);
```

error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<unsigned int, threadData>::insert(int, threadData&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_map.h:500:7: note: candidates are: std::pair<typename std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Rep_type::iterator, bool> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type&) [with _Key = unsigned int, _Tp = threadData, _Compare = std::less<unsigned int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, threadData> >, typename std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Rep_type::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, threadData> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair<const unsigned int, threadData>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_map.h:540:7: note:                 std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type&) [with _Key = unsigned int, _Tp = threadData, _Compare = std::less<unsigned int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, threadData> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, threadData> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair<const unsigned int, threadData>]
tcpClient.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’
```

Comment: Just one remark, using `typedef` to name structure is useless in C++.

Comment: Consider using `std::string` instead of `char*`. If you dynamically allocate memory for `message` you need to write copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor for `threadData`.

Comment: Someone's mixing C and C++...

Comment: and -1 for clearly not bothering to read the documentation for `std::map::insert`

Comment: @Ugo: it's not useless in C++, it's just not necessary with a typical C++ style.

Comment: @Anisha: normally in C++ you would just write `struct threadData { ... };`. In C if you do that then to refer to the type you have to use `struct threadData`. However C++ allows you to refer to the type as `threadData` even without the typedef.

Comment: @Anisha: 9.1/2 ([class.name]) in the standard describes how to refer to a user-defined type in C++, and almost every example bit of C++ code in every book or tutorial in the world shows the use of the class name alone ;-) I suppose it's less common to describe it in terms of the difference between C++ and C, most authors just describe the C++ behavior.

Comment: @Anisha: I haven't read the whole thing, and I don't normally read more than a few pages in order, but I've probably read almost all of the C++03 standard up to where the libraries start, and then some fraction of the libraries as I've needed them. C++11 is "the same shape" as C++03, more or less the same chapters in the same order, but with different content, so I'm less familiar with it but I can still normally find what I need. I certainly haven't memorized it, I can't quote it from memory, but I often remember enough of the bit I want to find it with text search or from the contents page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a pair for the `insert` function, because in common with other containers `insert` takes the `value_type`, which in the case of `map` is a pair -- each entry has a key and a mapped value. The `value_type` represents one entry in the container and hence includes both.

You could write `serverPortNumberThreadId[3490] = obj;` instead, if you prefer the look of it. Behavior is sometimes different (`insert` does nothing if the key already exists, whereas this code overwrites it, but unless you're relying on that behavior of `insert` already this makes no difference to you). Performance might be slightly different in terms of the number of `threadData` objects created/copied/assigned.

Answer (score 8):

You need to insert the value into map:

```
serverPortNumberThreadId.insert ( std::make_pair( 3490, obj) );
```

For other ways to insert into map, see the [map::insert() reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/).

Comment: This means that passing anything beyond the constants like 1,2 etc will need a pair?

Comment: @AnishaKaul No. The map's value is a pair. When inserting elements into a map, you need to insert a pair if you use the 1st insert from the page I linked. If you use the 2nd or 3rd insert, you do not need a pair.

Comment: and in that link two ways of inserting elements have been shown. Pair is needed when you need to insert two things in place of one. My structure is one object, not sure why it needs a pair?

Comment: @AnishaKaul Actually, that links shows 3 ways of inserting elements into map. The map's value is of type std::pair< key, value >. When using the 1st insert, you need to create a pair, where the 1st element in the key, and the 2nd is the value (the object in your example)

Comment: Yeah, I have realized my fault, I was "imagining" this syntax:  `x.insert (11, 12);`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
 //always overwrites the old value
 serverPortNumberThreadId[3490]=obj;
 //only insert a new one
 serverPortNumberThreadId.insert(std::make_pair(3490, obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to send a `pair` to insert function and not `key,value`.

```
mymap.insert ( pair<unsigned int,threadData>(3490, obj) );
```